# How do I use a new directory location for a new project and its main.py file in buildozer deploys for android?

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

Using [this tutorial][1], and after troubleshooting several issues that got in the way, I have successfully deployed the KivyHelloWorld main.py file onto my Android using buildozer in. This was done by creating a VM VirtualBox Ubuntu image on my PC and then running the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install git 
git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer.git 
cd buildozer 
sudo apt-get install python3.6 
sudo apt-get install -y python3-setuptools 
sudo python3 setup.py install 
cd .. 
git clone https://github.com/Dirk-Sandberg/KivyHelloWorld
cd KivyHelloWorld 
buildozer init 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev 
pip3 install --user --upgrade cython virtualenv 
sudo apt-get install cython 
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

My question is...From here, if I wanted to create a new project. Let's call it, "print("Hello Andrew") for example, in a new directory (so "cd.." then "cd NewProject") how would I go about do this? I tried copying the main.py into a new folder and then rerunning the buildozer init and deploy commands but it doesn't seem to work and errors out. Is there something I am missing or do I just have to keep making projects to the KivyHelloWorld directory over and over again?

**Update:** If I create the new directory (call it Test) and a change to that directory and paste a duplicate main.py in that Test folder and run these two commands:

```
buildozer init
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

I get this error:

```
user123@user123-VirtualBox:~/KivyHelloWorld$ cd
user123@user123-VirtualBox:~$ cd Test
user123@user123-VirtualBox:~/Test$ buildozer init
File buildozer.spec created, ready to customize!
user123@user123-VirtualBox:~/Test$ buildozer android debug deploy run
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Create directory /home/user123/Test/bin
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.7 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/user123/.local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
# Cwd /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
# Run 'git branch -vv'
# Cwd /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
* master 5a94d074 [origin/master] Merge pull request #2244 from Chronolife-team/native_services_upstream
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517<0.7.0"\' \'toml\''
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/user123/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/user123/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 19c
# Android NDK found at /home/user123/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
# Check application requirements
# Compile platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py'
# Cwd /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
/home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py:84: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 27
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (27)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 27 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK: /home/user123/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
[INFO]:    Found NDK version 19c
[INFO]:    Getting NDK API version (i.e. minimum supported API) from user argument
[INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.9
[INFO]:    No existing dists meet the given requirements!
[INFO]:    No dist exists that meets your requirements, so one will be built.
[INFO]:    Found a single valid recipe set: ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'setuptools', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
[INFO]:    The selected bootstrap is sdl2
[INFO]:    # Creating dist with sdl2 bootstrap
[INFO]:    Dist will have name myapp and requirements (python3, kivy)
[INFO]:    Dist contains the following requirements as recipes: ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'setuptools', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
[INFO]:    Dist will also contain modules (certifi) installed from pip
[INFO]:    Dist will be build in mode debug
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Recipe build order is ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'setuptools', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
[INFO]:    The requirements (certifi) were not found as recipes, they will be installed with pip.
[INFO]:    # Downloading recipes 
[INFO]:    Downloading hostpython3
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/user123/Test/....(and 65 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/hostpython3
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org...(and 34 more)
[INFO]:    hostpython3 download already cached, skipping                       
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading libffi
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/user123/Test/....(and 60 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/libffi
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/lib...(and 33 more)
[INFO]:    libffi download already cached, skipping                            
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading openssl
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/user123/Test/....(and 61 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/openssl
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.openssl.or...(and 30 more)
[INFO]:    openssl download already cached, skipping                           
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/user123/Test/....(and 64 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.or...(and 52 more)
[INFO]:    sdl2_image download already cached, skipping                        
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/user123/Test/....(and 64 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.or...(and 52 more)
[INFO]:    sdl2_mixer download already cached, skipping                        
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/user123/Test/....(and 62 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org...(and 48 more)
[INFO]:    sdl2_ttf download already cached, skipping                          
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading sqlite3
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/user123/Test/....(and 61 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/sqlite3
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.sqlite.org...(and 37 more)
[INFO]:    sqlite3 download already cached, skipping                           
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading python3
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/user123/Test/....(and 61 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/python3
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org...(and 34 more)
[INFO]:    python3 download already cached, skipping                           
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/user123/Test/....(and 58 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/sdl2
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org...(and 26 more)
[INFO]:    sdl2 download already cached, skipping                              
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading setuptools
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/user123/Test/....(and 64 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/setuptools
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.o...(and 53 more)
[INFO]:    setuptools download already cached, skipping                        
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading six
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/user123/Test/....(and 57 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/six
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.or...(and 41 more)
[INFO]:    six download already cached, skipping                               
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/user123/Test/....(and 61 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kiv...(and 27 more)
[INFO]:    pyjnius download already cached, skipping                           
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Downloading android
[INFO]:    Skipping android download as no URL is set
[INFO]:    Downloading kivy
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/user123/Test/....(and 58 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/kivy
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kiv...(and 25 more)
[INFO]:    kivy download already cached, skipping                              
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    # Building all recipes for arch armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    # Unpacking recipes
[INFO]:    Unpacking hostpython3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org...(and 34 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop
[INFO]:    hostpython3 is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking libffi for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/lib...(and 33 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    libffi is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking openssl for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.openssl.or...(and 30 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/openssl/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    openssl is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.or...(and 52 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/jni
[INFO]:    sdl2_image is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_mixer for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.or...(and 52 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/jni
[INFO]:    sdl2_mixer is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_ttf for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org...(and 48 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/jni
[INFO]:    sdl2_ttf is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking sqlite3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.sqlite.org...(and 37 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    sqlite3 is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking python3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.python.org...(and 34 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    python3 is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org...(and 26 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/jni
[INFO]:    sdl2 is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking setuptools for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.o...(and 53 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    setuptools is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking six for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.or...(and 41 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/six/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    six is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Unpacking pyjnius for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kiv...(and 27 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/pyjnius-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    pyjnius is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    -> running rm -rf /home/user123/Test/.bu...(and 109 more)
[INFO]:    -> running cp -a /home/user123/Test/.bui...(and 212 more)
[INFO]:    Unpacking kivy for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kiv...(and 25 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/kivy/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
[INFO]:    kivy is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    # Prebuilding recipes
[INFO]:    Prebuilding hostpython3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    hostpython3 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for hostpython3[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    Applying patch patches/pyconfig_detection.patch
[INFO]:    -> running patch -t -d /home/user123/Tes...(and 242 more)
           working: 1 out of 1 hunk ignored                                    Exception in thread background thread for pid 5030:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1637, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2561, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2265, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh.py", line 865, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/patch -t -d /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3 -p1 -i /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/hostpython3/patches/pyconfig_detection.patch

  STDOUT:
can't find file to patch at input line 4
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff -Nru Python-3.8.2/Lib/site.py Python-3.8.2-new/Lib/site.py
|--- Python-3.8.2/Lib/site.py    2020-04-28 12:48:38.000000000 -0700
|+++ Python-3.8.2-new/Lib/site.py        2020-04-28 12:52:46.000000000 -0700
--------------------------
No file to patch.  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored


  STDERR:

[INFO]:    STDOUT:                                                             
    can't find file to patch at input line 4    
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?    
The text leading up to this was:    
--------------------------  
|diff -Nru Python-3.8.2/Lib/site.py Python-3.8.2-new/Lib/site.py    
|--- Python-3.8.2/Lib/site.py    2020-04-28 12:48:38.000000000 -0700    
|+++ Python-3.8.2-new/Lib/site.py        2020-04-28 12:52:46.000000000 -0700    
--------------------------  
No file to patch.  Skipping patch.  
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
[INFO]:    STDERR:
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1260, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 709, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 154, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 213, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 570, in build_recipes
    recipe.apply_patches(arch)
  File "/home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 539, in apply_patches
    self.apply_patch(
  File "/home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 248, in apply_patch
    shprint(sh.patch, "-t", "-d", build_dir, "-p1",
  File "/home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh.py", line 911, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh.py", line 841, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh.py", line 865, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/patch -t -d /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3 -p1 -i /home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/hostpython3/patches/pyconfig_detection.patch

  STDOUT:
can't find file to patch at input line 4
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff -Nru Python-3.8.2/Lib/site.py Python-3.8.2-new/Lib/site.py
|--- Python-3.8.2/Lib/site.py    2020-04-28 12:48:38.000000000 -0700
|+++ Python-3.8.2-new/Lib/site.py        2020-04-28 12:52:46.000000000 -0700
--------------------------
No file to patch.  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/user123/Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/user123-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1500,unix/user123-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1500'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     MANDATORY_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1464'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     PWD = '/home/user123/Test'
#     LOGNAME = 'user123'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = 'JS ERROR;JS LOG'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     HOME = '/home/user123'
#     USERNAME = 'user123'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6003'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/f70ee0ed_daa7_477d_a3d4_c2b6c2944f61'
#     INVOCATION_ID = 'deb9275068c5473cb64e3a3f5d99bbc8'
#     MANAGERPID = '1257'
#     GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = 'stderr'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     DEFAULTS_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'user123'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.95'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:31338'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = '/home/user123/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/user123/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/user123'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/user123/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/user123/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/user123/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Just run the buildozer commands again in the new directory.

Comment: Check my update section in my post. Was this what you meant by run the buildozer commands again in the new directory. I ran those two commands with just the main.py file in the new folder and it errored out. Included error.